# Comparing two arrays and put equal values in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i dont know how to proceed.

```
<h5>VLAN</h5>  

  <table class="tg">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-0lax"</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax"</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax"</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="change04()" checked="checked" disabled=true class="checkbox" name="chkbvlan01" id="chkbvlan01" data-vlan="1"><label><b>VLAN 1 - native</label>
        <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="change04()" checked="checked" disabled=true class="checkbox" name="chkbvlan02" id="chkbvlan02" data-vlan="80"><label><b>VLAN 80 - Management</label>
        <th class="tg-0lax"></th>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="change04()" checked="checked" disabled=true class="checkbox" name="chkbvlan03" id="chkbvlan03" data-vlan="81"><label><b>VLAN 81 - MESTEST</label>
        <br>
      </tr>
```

I have one array:

```
var vlans = [1,80,81,82,83]
```

and the second:

```
var name = Array();
var summary = Array();
document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox').forEach(item => {
            if(item.checked){
              name = [item.getAttribute("data-vlan")];
    

          };
        });
```

the second is filled by checkboxes, when they are checked.

This is working.

But I dont get it, how to compare these arrays.

At the end, I want to compare them, and write alle matching values in a new array.

But I dont get it working.

Please help.

Comment: pleaser add the html part as well.

Comment: added the html code

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all the checked checkboxes, probably the simplest way is as follows:

```js
   const values = [...document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')]
     .filter(i => i.checked)
     .map(i => i.getAttribute("data-vlan"));
```

If your `vlans` variable is a list of all possible vlan values then the intersection of the two arrays will simply be `values` as above.

However if `vlans` contains a subset of values then you can do it as follows:

```
   const vlans = [1,80,81,82,83];

   const values = [...document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')]
     .filter(i => i.checked)
     .map(i => i.getAttribute("data-vlan"));

   const filteredValues = values.filter(v => vlans.includes(v));
```

Where `filteredValues` is the list of numbers that exist in both `vlans` and `values`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = [];
let summary = [];
document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox").forEach((item) => {
  if (item.checked) {
    //Push the checked items to the variable name array
    name.push(+item.getAttribute("data-vlan"));
  }
});
//this to get intersection (How can I find matching values in two arrays)
const matchedValues = vlans.filter(element => name.includes(element)); 
console.log(matchedValues)
```

Please aware of this:

1. Declare a Array variable with the method new Array () is more verbose, just use []. for instance let name = [].
2. why you use var syntaxe ?
3. consider to properly name your variables(name,summary  .. not good )

Comment: I am getting error:

Uncaught TypeError: name.push is not a function

Comment: i've updated the code

Comment: The console.log command of console.log(matchedValues)
shows:
(0) []

So nothing added :/

Comment: Make sur that the values of the checked checkbox are a number , as i see they are a sting , il update the code one moment

Comment: note the + sign that will convert string to a number `name.push(+item.getAttribute("data-vlan"));`

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all checkbox and check the check. Then push the value to the array.

Please do not use `name` as global variable. This is predifined and use by the window object and contains the name.

By using a table and `<td>`, the inner HTML has to be inside of the tag.

```js
const
    vlans = [1, 80, 81, 82, 83], // what is this for?
    checked = [];

document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox').forEach(item => {
    if (item.checked) checked.push(item.getAttribute("data-vlan"));
});

console.log(checked);
```

```html
<h5>VLAN</h5>
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax">1</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">2</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" onchange="change04()" checked="checked" disabled=true class="checkbox" name="chkbvlan01" id="chkbvlan01" data-vlan="1"><label><b>VLAN 1 - native</label></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="change04()" checked="checked" disabled=true class="checkbox" name="chkbvlan02" id="chkbvlan02" data-vlan="80"><label><b>VLAN 80 - Management</label></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="change04()" checked="checked" disabled=true class="checkbox" name="chkbvlan03" id="chkbvlan03" data-vlan="81"><label><b>VLAN 81 - MESTEST</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

- HTML is very invalid.

  - `<th>` belong in `<thead>`
  - `<td>` belong in `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>`
- Add only the attributes you'll use. Don't clutter the elements with unnecessary attributes because you might overlook a few.

  - Each checkbox has `disabled` and `checked`. That means all checkboxes are stuck as checked so logically there's no need to even run a function to check if there's anything checked at all.
  - All `<input>`s have a `value` attribute, there's no need to use a `data-*` attribute.
- The constructor `Array()` is wrong.

  - Correct syntax: `const vlans = new Array(5)`
  - The `5` means it has a length of 5 "slots"
  - Always use the literal form instead: `const vlans = []`
- [Inline Event Handlers are Garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)

  - <s>Inline event handler</s>

    ```
    <input id="in1" onchange="doNotDo(this)"...>
    ```
  - Use either on event property...

    ```
    document.forms[0].in1.onchange = doThis;
    ```

    - or...
  - ...use an event listener (recommended)

    ```
    document.forms[0].in1.addEventListener('change', doThis);
    ```

### Changes

- Wrapped a `<form>` around the `<table>`.

  - `<form>` can listen for a "change" event and by [Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation), we can control how all checkboxes behave when un/checked.
  - `<thead>` has been added and 2 more columns (82 and 83) because it makes very little sense to have an array of 5 numbers and only 3 columns.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
// Declare arrays
const vlans = [1, 80, 81, 82, 83];
let checked = [];

/*
permArr = vlans
tempArr = checked
This returns the index of each match. It wouldn't be usefull if 
the result was the values, you'd end up with identical arrays.
*/
const compare = (permArr, tempArr) =>
  permArr.flatMap((num, idx) => tempArr.includes(num) ? [idx] : []);

const VLANXX = event => {
  // Collect all .chx into a NodeList then into an array
  const chx = [...document.querySelectorAll('.chx')];
  /*
  If a checkbox is checked, convert it's value from string
  to number, otherwise return nothing
  */
  checked = chx.flatMap(chk => chk.checked ? [parseInt(chk.value)] : []);

  console.clear();

  // Log checked array
  console.log(`Checked Values: ${JSON.stringify(checked)}`);

  // Invoke and log current(arr1, arr2) 
  console.log(`Index of Matches: ${JSON.stringify(compare(vlans, checked))}`);
};

// Reference the <form>
const UI = document.forms.UI;

// When "change" events fire on <form> invoke VLANXX(e)
UI.onchange = VLANXX;
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed
}

th {
  width: 20%
}

td {
  vertical-align: top
}

.as-console-row::after {
  width: min-content;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: max-content;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<form id='UI'>
  <table>
    <caption>VLAN 5</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>80</th>
        <th>81</th>
        <th>82</th>
        <th>83</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="chk1" class='chx' type="checkbox" value="1">
          <label for='chk1'>
      <b>VLAN 1 - Native</b>
      </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="chk2" class='chx' type="checkbox" value="80">
          <label for='chk2'>
      <b>VLAN 80 - Admin</b>
      </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="chk3" class='chx' type="checkbox" value="81">
          <label for='chk3'>
      <b>VLAN 81 - MESTEST</b>
      </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="chk4" class='chx' type="checkbox" value="82">
          <label for='chk4'>
      <b>VLAN 82 - Hardware</b>
      </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="chk5" class='chx' type="checkbox" value="83">
          <label for='chk5'>
      <b>VLAN 83 - Network</b>
      </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```